# Redux-Form repeatable field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using Redux-Form v.5.2.3. I have a text input that needs to be repeated x number of times, depending on how many times a user clicks a button. 
Currently, because I am generating the same input field with the same field name, it does not work. When I type something on one input, it automatically types the same thing in the other inputs - that is because of the same name.

I am thinking of generating a unique id and appending that to the field 'name' - for example :

Original field:

Name: `<input type="text" {...name}>`

2nd Field - generated after the button press:

Name: `<input type="text" {...name2}>`

X field - generated after x button presses:

Name:    `<input type="text" {...nameX}>`

Any ideas if that works and an example how to implement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `key`, that will differentiate it. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html

Comment: I am not sure that is the right way to do it in Redux-Form ?

Comment: I think I've used a field as an array and I handled its change manually and just change the proper index with each specified field.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh - Could you elaborate on that or give an example ? As far as I am aware, you define some fields, eg: `export const fields = ['name', 'age'];` (surely in the fields array you CAN autogenerate some fields automatically) that the redux-form then puts into the React component - `export default reduxForm({
    form: 'ManagePerson',
    fields,
    asyncValidate
})(ManagePerson)` - So how would you obtain those auto-generated fields so you can use them here - `<input type="text" {...nameX}>`, where nameX is the autogenerated field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [deep forms](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/deep?_k=8asgja) in the RF docs.

Trying to figure this out as well, but from what I understand, you can define an array of fields by using the `[]` notation.

```
export const fields = [
  'name[]',
];
```

Then you add additional fields by using `addField(value?, index?)`. You can then access each field by treating `this.props.fields.name` as the array of `name` fields.

For your case, I think it should look something like

```
<div>
  {this.props.fields.name.map((field, index) => (
    <input key={index} type="text" {...field} />
  )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [redux-from v6.0.0](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/tree/v6.0.0-rc.5). In this version you can use [FieldArray](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/examples/fieldArrays/) for array fields.